# Server push message with JMS messaging to a JSF web application

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish, jms, java-ee-6

I'm writing two web application that simulate the Publisher/Subscriber pattern. A client add a subscription from a JSF web application into a database through an EJB bean in the back end. Another client then publish a message from another JSF web application using the same EJB bean in the backend. This EJB bean need to notify all subscribers that match the published message. I'm looking for a way to notify all subscribers with something like JMS. It's doesn't matter if I use JMS or not but I have to use JSF and the notification must be asynchronous.

I was looking for something like [Push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) and [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) and I found something in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8881137/680740). This example use [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) which is compatible with JMS and JSF but it does NOT shows how to receive a message or use JMS. I found also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8836405/680740) that explain how to not use JMS with RichFaces but like I said I want to use JMS and maybe it's my only solution to send/receive a message from a EJB bean. All the solution I found use only JSF Managed bean but what if you have to receive a notification from a EJB bean?

Comment: I have looked at your site but I cannot find an example. Before working on that I want to evaluate it and find the best solution. I have a short time deadline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `WebSockets` is the technology you are looking fore. Take a look at [PrimePush](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/push/index.jsf)
for an implementation in *PrimeFaces*.

You can combine this with [SEAM-JSF](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/JMSModule) to have access to JMS resources via CDI annotations in your backing beans.

Comment: I'm already using PrimeFaces and I looked at PrimePush but in that example you can push only from a Managed bean. I need to receive message published from a EJB bean.

Comment: What do you mean "backing bean"?

Comment: oh, afaik _backing bean_ and _managed bean_ are synonyms. E.g. `@Named` or `@ManagedBean`. What is a _EJB Bean_? ;-) ... You can use `@ManagedBean @Stateless`.

Comment: JSF ManagedBean or backing bean should be different from a normal bean inside a JEE container (called Enterprise bean or EJB bean). The latter is inside a container and the first is inside a http session. Anyway can you point me to an example of CDI annotations used to access a JMS queue?

Comment: See the reference guide: http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/jms/latest/reference/en-US/html/

Comment: I think it's what I'm looking for. I have read you can handle message from jms queue, but can you integrate CDI annotation with PrimePush?

Comment: I found this solution http://seamframework.org/Seam3/FacesModule. It says that you can extend JSF to integrate it with the other Seam modules like JMS module. I will git it a try.

Comment: If I decide to use JBoss I cannot use Glassfish, right? Are they two application servers?

Comment: Of course you can use CDI with _PrimeFaces_ and _PrimePush_. And yes, you are right. _JBossAS_ and _Gassfish_ are application server.

Comment: If you can show me an example of CDI that can work like a MessageDrivenBean (receive asynchronous message with a method like "onMessage") and at the same time can update the JSF with Primefaces I will be happy to start a bounty and give you 50 points.

Comment: I think the best solution for me is this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/2676117/680740. It uses a simple but effective method to implement a server push without JMS and complicated frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMS for that but broadcasting messages you would have to handle yourself so at the end it doesn't matter if you use JMS for this scenario or not, just the part sending/handling the published message will differ.

Example: client uses JSF application which forwards the message to the JMS queue/topic. Another JSF application (JMS client) will receive the message with the MDB, parse it and retrieve the list of recipients from the database and assigning the message to each one, again using the database.

As you can see all happens with simple db data handling and using JMS is not necessary, you can use any EJB or Servlet to do the processing of the message for  you.

On the JSF application which should receive the message you can use AJAX mechanism polling the database for new messages assigned to the specific user.

Comment: I was thinking to this solution, but unfortunately I cannot use it. This project is an assignment from my professor. I explained it to him but he said that I need to maintain the notification asynchronous otherwise the Publish/subscribe pattern will loose its identity.